# sql daterange stores not the time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update my daterange but it stores not the time

```
UPDATE booking SET booking_range = '[2023-01-01 09:00:00, 2023-01-05 09:00:00]'::daterange;
```

here is the result

```
      business_id: 2,
      booking_range: '[2023-01-01,2023-01-06)'
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: 1) Using a `daterange` instead of a `tstzrange` per [Range Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html). 2) What is the data type of `booking_range`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the type of booking_range is daterange

Comment: Well, a  date has not time, so obviously a date range can't store the time. You need to use `tsrange` or `tstzrange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing truncation because of your explicit `::daterange` cast as well as the column data type. Type `date` holds only the year, month and day, `time` holds only the hour and minute while [`timestamps` hold both date and time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html). They all accept `'2023-01-06 01:23:45'` input, but they discard whatever they can't hold:

```sql
select '2023-01-06 01:23:45'::time,     --01:23:45
       '2023-01-06 01:23:45'::date,     --2023-01-06
       '2023-01-06 01:23:45'::timestamp;--2023-01-06 01:23:45
select 'allballs'::time,               --00:00:00
       'yesterday allballs'::date,     --2023-03-15
       'yesterday at allballs'::date,  --2023-03-15
       'yesterday at 11:00 pm'::date,  --2023-03-15
       'yesterday'::timestamp,            --2023-03-15 00:00:00
       'yesterday allballs'::timestamp,   --2023-03-15 00:00:00
       'yesterday at allballs'::timestamp,--2023-03-15 00:00:00
       'yesterday at 11:00 pm'::timestamp;--2023-03-15 23:00:00
```

Lower and upper bound of `daterange` is a `date`, which is why it discarded the hour and minute.

In certain situations PostgreSQL implicitly uses predefined [CAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html)s to process your input. In `psql` you can list them with [`\dC` meta-command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS) along with the information where you can expect them to be applied implicitly.

To solve the problem, your column type can be changed in-place: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/zE2lfXNM)

```sql
ALTER TABLE booking  
    ALTER COLUMN booking_range SET DATA TYPE tsrange 
    USING tsrange(  lower(booking_range )::timestamp
                  , upper(booking_range )::timestamp+'1 day'::interval
                  , CASE WHEN lower_inc(booking_range ) THEN '[' ELSE '(' END
                  ||CASE WHEN lower_inc(booking_range ) THEN ']' ELSE ')' END );
```

The +`'1 day'::interval` might be useful because once you change the bounds to `timestamp`, your current dates will get time `00:00:00`, making ranges spanning two dates implying full 48h, two full shifts, suddenly end up lasting 24 instead of 48 hours. It might be counter-intuitive because everything gets "shifted" so a better alternative would be to add a default opening time on lower bound and closing time on upper bound. If you're dealing with different timezones, make sure to account for it using `tstzrange`, `at time zone` construct and time zone offsets or names.

Comment: thank you for your good explained comment. I use tsrange because I build a renting software and when anyone rent on 2023-09-09 10:00:00 to 2023-09-11 10:00:00 I have to say the "to_date" have to be available so I make ')'