# check range but the to_date should available

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to check two dates between given range in a field. It works perfect except one thing.

I have a renting software and the people can choose when to rent a car

from_date 2023-03-22T09:00:00
to_date 2023-03-30T09:00:00

When anyone rents from date x TO date y then Date y (2023-03-30T09:00:00) should available because on date y the car is not in rent and given back. But in range it says it exists. how can I say now to my range that the date y (to_date) is available?

to_date
2023-03-30T08:59:99 = blocked (of course because its in the range)
2023-03-30T09:00:00 = blocked // this should be free (this is in the range but it gives the car back so at this time it should be free but it is in the range how can I make it not in the range ?
2023-03-30T09:01:00 = free // of course its free it is not anymore in the range

code:

```
SELECT * FROM booking WHERE '[2023-03-22T09:00:00.000Z, 2023-03-30T09:00:00.000Z]'::tstzrange && booking_range
```

Thank you for your help Idk any further

Comment: Given your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75748796/sql-daterange-stores-not-the-time) you seem to have a problem distinguishing between `date` and `timestamp`.  You are **not**  working over a date range but a timestamp range. And again I point you at [Range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE). In particular *8.17.7. Discrete Range Types* and how that differs between dates and timestamps. **Read the docs and learn**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly: you want the upper end of the range to be excluded. If that is the case, use a parenthesis for the upper end:

```
'[2023-03-22 09:00:00,2023-03-30 09:00:00)'::tstzrange
                                         ^
                                         |
                                       here
```

That would not overlap with a second range that starts at `2023-03-30 09:00:00`.

Comment: I dont want the end date included, so when the last date in the range of the time is 09:00:00 it should not included but 08:59:59. exp: from_date(2023, 10, 11, 9, 0, 0) to_date( 2023, 10, 11, 9, 0, 0) so the to_date with 9, 0, 0 should not included but the to_date until 8:59:59 should included

Comment: That's exactly what my answer does.

Comment: You are not looking for the last `date` in the range you are looking for the last `timestamp`, failure to understand the difference will cause you to not  understand  the answer for this. Read the link I posted in my comment above and to your previous question and see why what @LaurenzAlbe posted is correct.

Comment: thanks now I understand this thanks for your both!